# Many to many realtionship with resource controller without model laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

i am a new php programmer and i just started with laravel, i am trying to build a library application and at the moment i am working on the loans part. basically i have a pivot table named **copy_user** with the following columns: ('copy_id', 'user_id', 'date', 'return_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at') copy_id is one of many copies that could be linked to a book in the books table. basically i on the user model i have this code:

```
public function loanedCopies() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Copy::class)->withPivot('date', 'return_date');
    }
```

while on the copy model i have that:

```
public function loaningUsers() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot(['date', 'return_date']);
    }
```

than i created a view for the loans which will show the content of the content of the table copy_user so i also created a LoanController and a route to use the resource controller like that:

```
Route::resource('loans', LoanController::class);
```

now what i'm trying to do is to delete or edit the records on the copy_user table by using the resource WITHOUT using a model, and i'm trying to do so like that:

code on the view:

```
<form action="/loans/{{$copy->id}}?user_id={{$user->id}}&date={{$copy->pivot->date}}" method="POST">
          @csrf
          @method('DELETE')
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</form>
```

code in the controller:

```
public function destroy(Copy $copy)
    {
        $request = Request::capture();
        $request->get('user_id');
        $request->get('date');
        $copy->loaningUsers()->where('id', $request->get('user_id'))->wherePivot('date', $request->get('date'))->detach();
        return redirect('/loans');
    }
```

Now the problem is that the destroy method is not receiving any data so it's not deleting anything. I was specifically told to do so without using a model for loans but i don't know if it's possible. using the resource controller was my decision but i don't know if it's the right way to go, does any body know why this doesn't work? thanks in advance to every body who will answare!

Answer (score 0):

Since your resource is named loans, the destroy method will expect you to use $loan as it's parameter in order to bind data.

```
Route::resource('loans', LoanController::class); //This expects you to pass $loan


public function destroy(Copy $loan) { //Switch from $copy to $loan

}
```

You can also verify this by checking the routes using:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 0):

thankyou Vimona , just got back on that project and i ditched the resource controller in favor of normal routing for the loans by doing the following:

```
Route::get('/loans', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoanController@index');
Route::delete('/loans/{copy}', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoanController@destroy');
```

and on the controller i left the method as it was:

```
public function destroy(Copy $copy)
{
    $request = Request::capture();
    $request->get('user_id');
    $request->get('date');
    $copy->loaningUsers()->where('id', $request->get('user_id'))->wherePivot('date', $request->get('date'))->detach();
    //$copy->loaningUsers()->detach();
    return redirect('/loans');
}
```

by doing that now the the delete method works fine, hopefully i didn't make any mistake, if so, please tell me so i can try to fix it!